Are extra flags discarded in TCP exchanges?
A "normal" TCP handshake looks like this:
MachineA → SYN → MachineB
Machine B → SYN,ACK → MachineA
MachineA → ACK → MachineB

This means that for each step, a flag (or set of flags) is expected to be set in the packet.
Are extra flags discarded when the expected flag is there, or is a packet with extra flags treated as incorrect? In other words, would the following sequence be treated by MachineB as a full, correct handshake?
MachineA → SYN → MachineB
Machine B → SYN,ACK → MachineA
MachineA → ACK,RST,FIN → MachineB

ACK is present in the last packet (so the handshake could be seen as finalized), but there is also an RST and FIN flag (this is just an example of extraneous flag(s)).
My question is general - the initial handshake is only an example, I am interested in the general case of discarding or not extra flags over other sequences as well.

Note that nonsensical combinations of flags have been used to trigger crashes or to fingerprint the OS in various IP stack implementations over the years.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christmas_tree_packet

Neither of them are extraneous on their own, technically, even if the full combination in your example is indeed excessive.
"the 3rd packet of the handshake expects a ACK" is an oversimplification – the TCP handshake was never actually specified as having this rigid
SYN→SYN,ACK→ACK form. Rather, each flag has a specific function and specific state transitions which leads to a typical handshake having this form.
More generally, the function of the handshake is:

Machine A sends a SYN, which machine B ACKs.
Machine B sends a SYN, which machine A ACKs.
When both have ACK'd each other's initial SYN packet, the connection is now established.

Even if the ACK from machine B is merged with the SYN, these are still just separate operations and even the specification describes it as a logically four-way handshake where some steps "can be combined" into a three-way one – and usually are, but that's not set in stone.

For example, it is legal for both hosts to send their SYNs at once, crossing paths (not that it happens in practice, I assume), leading to a SYN⇄SYN / SYN,ACK⇄SYN,ACK exchange – called a "simultaneous open" in TCP.

On the other hand, while the specification does say that a received SYN should be followed up with sending a SYN,ACK in return, it is still not an error if just an ACK without SYN is received in step two – it's a valid ACK although it has no effect on advancing the handshake.


Likewise, the FIN→FIN,ACK→ACK sequence consists of two distinct FIN→ACK sequences where each machine ACK's the received FIN, and it's legal – and common – to have a "half-closed" connection where one side has issued a FIN but the other merely ACKs it but continues sending data.
So regarding your example:

Machine-B is in the SYN-RECEIVED state when it receives the 3rd packet.

It is allowed to have RST set at this point, which would close the connection without fully establishing it – not as an invalid handshake packet, but as a valid RST.
The specification doesn't state anything about FIN being checked at this point – that's only done if there is no RST.

It is also allowed to have FIN set at this point, which – if the RST weren't there – would have the same effect as if the connection were in ESTABLISHED state.
(Note that the same section only says "send an acknowledgement for the FIN"; it doesn't say anything about sending another FIN in return – that has to be explicitly done by the software closing the socket.)


Having both FIN and RST on the same packet is indeed weird, but in this case the RST will take effect first and (going by the algorithm detailed in the spec) the FIN will never be checked.

My question is general - the initial handshake is only an example, I am interested in the general case of discarding or not extra flags over other sequences as well.

There is no general case of "extra flags"; the specification lists what flags the receiver should check in each state, and the response depends on the flag and the state. For example, URG flag in the CLOSING state is specified as "Ignore the URG", while in SYN-SENT state it is processed as usual (as the SYN packet is allowed to contain regular data).

Thank you. This is very clear now. I never knew that SYN,ACK is actually SYN for one reason and ACK for another one, combined. Your example made it very clear.

"Not that it happens in practice" - it does happen in P2P networks. It's tough across the internet though as it might require NAT hole punching.
